# Second derivative near a minimum positive?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

If I have a smooth real valued non-constant function $f$ with isolated minimum at $x_M$ does that mean that close to $x_M$ its second derivative must be positive? I.e. must there exist $a > 0$ so that

$$
\begin{align}
f''(x_M + \varepsilon) > 0 \\
f''(x_M - \varepsilon) > 0
\end{align}
$$

for all $\varepsilon \in (0, a]?$ If not can someone give an example?

Comment: It’s true. But a small correction: there exists a positive $a$.

Comment: What do you mean by "isolated minimum"?

Comment: @GregMartin I mean with that $f(x) > f(x_M)$ for $x$ near $x_M$.

Comment: Take $x^4$ as an counterexample.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How is this a counterexample? The second derivative of $x^4$ is $12 x^2$ which is always positive away from the minimum at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nothing can be said about the sign of $f''$ in the vicinity of an isolated minimum.

An example is the function $f$ defined by
$$
 f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}\left(3 + 2 \sin(\frac {1}{x^2})\right)
$$
for $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. $f$ is infinitely often differentiable and has an absolute minimum at $x=0$. For $x \ne 0$ is
$$
 f''(x) = \frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^6 }
\left( 6 - 8 \cos(\frac {1}{x^2}) - 9x^2+6x^2\cos(\frac {1}{x^2})-6x^2\sin(\frac {1}{x^2})\right) \, .
$$
For sufficiently small $|x|$ is
$$
f''(x) \le \frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^6 }
\left( 7 - 8 \cos(\frac {1}{x^2})\right)
$$
and that is negative if $\cos(1/x^2) = 1$, which happens arbitrarily close to zero.